# Twilio ValidationCode is not showing up my PHP page?

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I'm trying to follow the instructions shown on this page: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/outgoing-caller-ids  to `verify` a number and add that number to my twilio account as a `caller ID`.

However, when I open my PHP page in the browser, I don't see any `ValidationCode` in my page to be able to enter it via the phone!

My account is a full account and has credits in it so the issue is not that.

also, when I open my PHP Page, the phone number provided rings but as I stated above, I don't see any verification Code in my php page to be able to use it to verify the number!

This is the code I am using from the pag above:

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('path/to/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
$token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

$caller_id = $client->account->outgoing_caller_ids->create("+44myphonenumber", array(
        "FriendlyName" => "Michelle"
    ));
echo $caller_id->sid;
?>
```

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: Are you getting any error

Comment: @Uchiha, No, nothing at all.. I even looked in my error_log file and there is nothing there either!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what twilio support told me to use right at the bottom of my php code and it worked fine:

```
echo $caller_id->validation_code;
```